# How to assign the .lines Seq to a variable and iterate over it?

Tags: raku

Assigning an iterator to variable changes apparently how the `Seq` behaves. E.g.

```
use v6;

my $i = '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
say $i.WHAT;
say '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines.WHAT;
.say for $i;
.say for '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
```

results in:

```
(Seq)
(Seq)
(DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04 DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS")
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

So once assigned I get only the string representation of the sequence. I know I can use `.say for $i.lines` to get the same output but I do not understand the difference between the assigned and unassigned iterator/Seq.

Comment: Because you assign the `Seq` to `$i` (not `@i`) for doesn't know to iterate over it but treats it as a single thing.
If you want to iterate over it either assign is to `@i` or tell for it's iterable with `@$i`

Comment: Or Slip it with `.say for |$i`

Comment: What method can I use to see that better than `.WHAT` as it does not make the difference clear?

Comment: Personally, I always use [dd](https://docs.perl6.org/programs/01-debugging#index-entry-dd)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assignment in Perl 6 is always about putting something *into* something else.

Assignment into a `Scalar` (`$` sigil) stores the thing being assigned into a `Scalar` container object, meaning it will be treated as a single item; this is why `for $item { }` will not do an iteration. There are various ways to overcome this; the most conceptually simple way is to use the `<>` postfix operator, which strips away any `Scalar` container:

```
my $i = '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
.say for $i<>;
```

There's also the slip operator ("flatten into"), which will achieve the same:

```
my $i = '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
.say for |$i;
```

Assignment into an `Array` will - unless the right-hand side is marked lazy - iterate it and store each element into the `Array`. Thus:

```
my @i = '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
.say for @i;
```

Will work, but it will eagerly read all the lines into `@i` before the loop starts. This is OK for a small file, but less ideal for a large file, where we might prefer to work lazily (that is, only pulling a bit of the file into memory at a time). One might try:

```
my @i = lazy '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
.say for @i;
```

But that won't help with the retention problem; it just means the array will be populated lazily from the file as the iteration takes place. Of course, sometimes we might *want* to go through the lines multiple times, in which case assignment into an `Array` would be the best choice.

By contrast, declaring a symbol and binding it to that:

```
my \i = '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
.say for i;
```

Is not a "put into" operation at all; it just makes the symbol `i` refer to exactly what `lines` returns. This is rather clearer than putting it into a `Scalar` container only to take it out again. It's also a little easier on the reader, since a `my \foo = ...` can never be rebound, and so the reader doesn't need to be on the lookup for any potential changes later on in the code.

As a final note, it's worth knowing that the `my \foo = ...` form is actually a binding, rather than an assignment. Perl 6 allows us to write it with the `=` operator rather than forcing `:=`, even if in this case the semantics are `:=` semantics. This is just one of a number of cases where a declaration with an initializer differs a bit from a normal assignment, e.g. `has $!foo = rand` actually runs the assignment on every object instantiation, while `state $foo = rand` only runs it only if we're on the first entry to the current closure clone.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to iterate over the sequence you need to either assign it to a positional :

`my @i = '/etc/lsb-release'.IO.lines;
.say for @i;`

Or you can tell the iterator that you want to treat the given thing as iterable :

`.say for @$i`

Or you can Slip it into a list for the iterator :

`.say for |$i`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I have not been using any `Perl` for a while and just ignored there are contexts :D

Comment: You can also [`.cache`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq#(PositionalBindFailover)_method_cache) it.

Comment: or use binding `my $i := ...`

Comment: Bindings make the variable immutable, though.